# JQuery DataTables 1.10.12 issue with JQuery 3.1.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

We have upgraded our app to latest Bootstrap (3.3.7) and JQuery (3.1.0) with JQuery DataTables (1.10.12).

Here's the included scripts.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Datatables module code.

```
var tables = {},

initTable : function(tableID, target, settings){

        var searchSettList, map, i, l, paging = settings.paging;

        if(paging){
            settings["drawCallback"] = function(settings) {
                resetPageIndices(settings.oInit);
            };
        }

        tables[tableID] = $(target).DataTable(settings);

        if(settings.paging)
            setPagingEventListeners(tables[tableID],settings.pagingElements);

        if(settings.searching && settings.hasOwnProperty("searchSettingsInfo")){

            searchSettList = settings.searchSettingsInfo;

            for(i=0,l=searchSettList.length;i<l;i++){

                map = searchSettList[i];

                if(map.type == "string"){
                    $(map.watchChange).on(map.watchEvent, {index : map.columnIndex, table :tables[tableID]},function(e){
                        e.data.table.columns(e.data.index).search($(this).val()).draw();
                    });
                }
                if(map.type == "regex"){
                    $(map.watchChange).on(map.watchEvent, {index : map.columnIndex, table :tables[tableID]},function(e){
                        e.data.table.columns(e.data.index).search($(this).val(),true).draw();
                    });
                }
                else if(map.type == "rangeSearch"){
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(insertRangeSearch(map.columnIndex,target, map.minEl, map.maxEl));
                    $(map.minEl+","+map.maxEl).on(map.watchEvent,{table :tables[tableID]}, function(e){
                        e.data.table.draw();
                    });
                }
                else if(map.type == "searchList"){
                    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(insertListSearch(map.columnIndex,target, map.searchInputTag));
                    $(map.searchInputTag).bind(map.watchEvent,{table :tables[tableID]}, function(e){
                        e.data.table.draw();
                    });
                }
                /*else if(map.type == "clearAllSearchFilters"){
                    $(map.watchChange).on(map.watchEvent,{tableID :tableID}, function(e){
                        clearAllSearchFilters(e.data.tableID);
                    });
                }*/
            }
        }
    },

insertRangeSearch = function(columnIndex, tableTag, fromEl, toEl){

    return function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {

        if(settings.oInstance.selector != tableTag){
            console.info("wrong table: table is "+settings.oInstance.selector+", but function is for "+tableTag);
            return true;
        }

        var min = parseFloat( $(fromEl).val() ),
            max = parseFloat( $(toEl).val() ), 
            val = parseFloat( data[columnIndex] ) || 0;

        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && val <= max ) ||
             ( min <= val   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <= val   && val <= max ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
},

//searches for a string within a list (present in string form)
//each tag in the column (index of which is passed as argument) must have a list of values separated by a comma 
//the tag that contains the value to be searched must be passed to the function.
insertListSearch = function(columnIndex, tableTag, searchInputTag){

    return function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {

        if(settings.oInstance.selector != tableTag){
            console.info("wrong table: table is "+settings.oInstance.selector+", but function is for "+tableTag);
            return true;
        }

        var list = data[columnIndex].split(","),
            searchInput = $(searchInputTag).val();

        if(!searchInput)
            return true;

        if ( list.indexOf(searchInput) != -1)
            return true;
        return false;
    };
};
```

Example DataTable Initialization:

```
sandbox.tables.initTable(_tableID,_tableTag,
        {
            "paging":   true,
            "info":     false,
            "searching": true,
            columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: "disable_ordering",
                orderable: false
            },
            {
                targets: "disable_searching",
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                targets: "invisible_col",
                visible: false
            },
            {
                targets:   "created_col",
                orderData: [_createdDateLongCol]
            },
            {
                targets:   "localtime_col",
                orderData: [_localDateLongCol]
            },
            {
                targets:   "due_col",
                orderData: [_dueDateLongCol]
            },
            {
                targets:   "taskname_col",
                orderData: [_taskCommentsCol]
            },
            /*{
                targets:   "addedby_col",
                orderData : [_addedByNameCol]
            },*/
            {
                targets:   "status_col",
                type :     "string"
            }],
           "dom": 't',
           "order": [[ _dueDateLongCol, "asc" ]],
           "pageLength":10,
           "pagingElements":
            {
               "previousPageBt":"section#tasks ul.pagination li a.previousPage",
               "nextPageBt":"section#tasks ul.pagination li a.nextPage",
               "changePageSelect": "section#tasks select.pagination_rowslist",
               "startIndex" : "section#tasks .startIndex",
               "endIndex" : "section#tasks .endIndex",
               "totalRecords" : "section#tasks .totalRecords",
               "pagingEventPublish":"tasks-table-paging-event"
            },
           "searchSettingsInfo": 
            [
             {
                "watchChange" : "section#tasks aside select.filterstatus_list",
                "watchEvent": "change",
                "type": "string",
                "columnIndex":_statusCol
             },
             {
                "watchChange" : "section#tasks aside select.filtertype_list",
                "watchEvent": "change",
                "type": "string",
                "columnIndex":_typeCol
             },
             {
                    "watchChange" : "section#tasks aside select.filtertimezone_list",
                    "watchEvent": "change",
                    "type": "regex",
                    "columnIndex":_timeZoneCol
             },
             {
                "minEl" : "#taskListFilterFromDate",
                "maxEl": "#taskListFilterToDate",
                "watchEvent": "change",
                "type" : "rangeSearch",
                "columnIndex":_dueDateLongCol
             },
             {
                "searchInputTag" : "section#tasks aside select.filtertag_list",
                "watchEvent": "change",
                "type" : "searchList",
                "columnIndex":_tagsListStringCol
             },
             {
                "watchChange" : "#clearAllSearchFilters",
                "watchEvent": "click",
                "type" : "clearAllSearchFilters"
             }
            ],
            "tableID":_tableID
        });
```

Searching with string and regex works fine.

But rangeSearch - fromdate to todate and list search is not working and giving the following message.

```
wrong table: table is undefined, but function is for #tasklisting table.
```

If we bring old JQuery below 3.0.0 and old JQuery DataTable 1.10.9...It's working fine.

Please help in this regards. We need our system to use latest libraries.

Thanks in advance :)

Regards,
Ananthakrishnan.

Comment: Additional information: If we use latest JQuery DataTables 1.10.12 version with old JQuery 2.2.4 version, it is working fine.

When we upgrade JQuery to 3.0.0 or 3.1.0, that's when the datatables problem that i mentioned before is coming up. Most of the functionalities are working fine, except the custom defined functions for range search and list search.

Please suggest solutions for the same.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Found out the cause for the issue by myself. One of the method .selector is deprecated as of JQuery 3.1.0. Changed it. It's working fine.